# how to merge two streams and return list with different type?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

i have two streams and i want to combine them into list with different 
i.e i have hashmap

```
Map<String, List<String>> citiesByZip = new HashMap<>();
```

that hold this data

```
Alameda [95246, 95247]
Colusa [95987]
```

list of persons

```
  class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int income;
    private int zipCode;



 People(String firstName, String lastName, int income, int zipCode) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.income = income;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public int getIncome() {
        return income;
    }
    public int getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
}
 List<Person> persons= new ArrayList<>();
```

that hold this data

```
Junior Jane 20000 95246
Junior Jane 30000 95246
Joseph James 50000 95247
Patricia Allen 60000 95247
Opal Campbell 70000 95987
Dorothy Rook 80004 95987
Mary Nelson 80000 23666
```

i want to map each person in list to hashmap of counties to find which county person lives in

```
List <FinalObject> finalObjects= new  ArrayList<>();
finalObjects = Stream.concat(peopleStream.stream(), citiesByZip.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                ))
```

this list should return list of final objects 
like this

```
Junior Jane 20000 Alameda
Junior Jane 30000 Alameda
Joseph James 50000 Alameda
           .
           .
           etc
```

i know that i can do this job in Java 7 with tradition loops but i was wondering if i can do the same thing in java 8 using `stream and lambda`

Comment: Give us (compilable) sample data to work with.

Comment: I think you would need a map whose keys are zip code, and whose values are the city pertaining to that zip code.

Comment: @Alexander exactly, but I don't know how I can reference stream inside other stream

Comment: Give us (compilable) sample data to work with.

Comment: @Alexander sorry i do not know what you mean by (compilable) data. i have hashmap that hold this data `Alameda [95246, 95247]
Colusa [95987]` and list of persons that hold this data `Junior Jane 20000 95246
Junior Jane 30000 95246
Joseph James 50000 95247
Patricia Allen 60000 95247
Opal Campbell 70000 95987
Dorothy Rook 80004 95987
Mary Nelson 80000 23666`

Comment: I don't think it is possible to merge different datatypes i.e. list and map. It is always with same datatypes.

Comment: @kero I was asking for actual code (that we can compile) that contains your sample data. People don't want to waste their time converting your given text like `Junior Jane 20000 95246...` into the code they need, like `ArrayList<Person> people = Arrays.asList(new Person("Junior", "Jane", 200000, 95246), ...);`.

Comment: @kero You'll get more answers by reducing the barrier to entry of your question. For example, I would have answered this question the first time I saw it, but I was on mobile and the text processing I would have needed to just convert your data was what made me put off answering.'

Comment: @kero On an unrelated note, your `citiesByZip` map is actually more like `zipsByCity` (the zip codes are looked up by the city, not the other way as your name suggests). Also, take a look at [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Google's Guava library. It's perfect for your use case (mapping multiple zip codes value per each city key). There are methods for "inverting" multi maps, which would be able to generate a `citiesByZip` map given `zipsByCity`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need a data structure for an efficient lookup of a particular zip code, as `Map<String, List<String>>` is not suitable for that. You can convert it like

```
Map<Integer,String> zipToCity = citiesByZip.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Integer::valueOf)
                   .map(zip -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(zip, e.getKey())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Alternatively, you may use

```
Map<Integer,String> zipToCity = citiesByZip.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(HashMap::new,
            (m,e) -> e.getValue().forEach(zip -> m.put(Integer.valueOf(zip), e.getKey())),
            Map::putAll);
```

which doesn’t need temporary `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` instances, but looks much like the conventional iteration solution. In fact, for the sequential use case, the loop is actually simpler.

Then, you can convert the `Person` instances to `FinalObject` instances with a single stream operation. Since you didn’t specify the `FinalObject` class, I assume

```
class FinalObject {
    private String firstName, lastName, city;
    private int income;
    FinalObject(String firstName, String lastName, int income, String city) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.income = income;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public int getIncome() {
        return income;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return firstName+" "+lastName+" "+income+" "+city;
    }
}
```

With this definition, you can do the conversion with the zip lookup like

```
List<FinalObject> finalObjects = persons.stream()
    .map(p -> new FinalObject(p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName(),
                  p.getIncome(), zipToCity.getOrDefault(p.getZipCode(), "Unknown")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Though, it might be beneficial to use delegation instead:

```
class FinalObject {
    private Person p;
    String city;

    FinalObject(Person p, String city) {
        this.p = p;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return p.getFirstName();
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return p.getLastName();
    }
    public int getIncome() {
        return p.getIncome();
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return getFirstName()+" "+getLastName()+" "+getIncome()+" "+city;
    }
}
```

```
List<FinalObject> finalObjects = persons.stream()
    .map(p -> new FinalObject(p, zipToCity.getOrDefault(p.getZipCode(), "Unknown")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```